# Белая страница с ответом после отправки fetch

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

То, как я возвращаю ответ.

```
return response()->json(['message' => 'Запчасть зарегистрирована']);
```

То, как обрабатывает ответ js

```
fetch('/main', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    let messageElement = document.getElementById('message');
                    messageElement.textContent = data.message;
                })
```

То, что я получаю на выходе, это просто пустая страница со строкой:

```
{"message":"Запчасть зарегистрирована"}
```

Comment: 1. Не вижу `catch` 2.  Скрин ответа сервера, а то даже статус ответа не понятно. 3. Это весь скрипт на странице? Вы используете фреймворки?

Comment: А как оправляется запрос? Очень похоже что вы забыли отменить отправку формы…